# SwiftUI: Modify master view from detail

Tags: swiftui

I want to code my first iOS app using swiftUI. I have lots of programming experience, but all of it is from a long time ago. I thought I could learn swift quickly, but I was wrong. The world has changed...

I have a master view with a list of participants (an array called "activePersons") and for each participant there is a detail view ("EditPerson") that is supposed to allow to modify or remove the participant from the list. In order to add a new person, the last item in the list is not a person, but a symbol that points to a detail view ("NewPerson") that allows to select a new person.

Currently, I have defined the list of persons as global variables. Which, of course, doesn't cause the master view to update.

I've tried hard using a @State wrapper, but all of my attempts failed. Of course, I can define activePersons as a state variable within ContentView, but then I can't modify it from the detail views.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's my Code (excerpts):

```
import SwiftUI

struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

var activePersons: [Person] = [ Person(id: 1, name: "Dummy1")]
var otherPersons: [Person] = [  Person(id: 1, name: "Dummy2"),
                                Person(id: 2, name: "Dummy3"),
                                Person(id: 3, name: "Dummy4")]
...
```

and ContentView.swift reads:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {

                List {
                    ForEach(0..<activePersons.count, id: \.self) { value in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: EditPerson(),
                            label: {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(activePersons[value].name)
                                        .font(.system(size: 26, weight: .regular))
                         
                                }.padding(15)
                            })
                    }
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NewPerson(),
                        label: {
                            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                                .font(.system(size: 26, weight: .light))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.7, green: 0.7, blue: 0.7))
                                .padding(15)
                        })
                }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 30)
                .navigationTitle("Participants")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                Text("Planning")
            }
...
```

NewPerson.swift (one of the detail views that modify the list of participants):

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewPerson: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<otherPersons.count) { value in
                Button(action: {
                    activePersons.append(otherPersons[value])
                }) {
                Text(otherPersons[value].name)
                }
            }
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 30)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you're going to want to pass state down into child views using either Bindings or ObservableObjects. The following code illustrates both:

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
}

class AppState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var activeIds : [Int] = [0,1]
    @Published var persons: [Person] = [Person(id: 0, name: "Dummy1"),
                                    Person(id: 1, name: "Dummy2"),
                                    Person(id: 2, name: "Dummy3"),
                                    Person(id: 3, name: "Dummy4")]
    
    var activePersons : [Person] {
        return activeIds.compactMap { id in
            persons.first(where: { $0.id == id
            })
        }
    }
    
    var nonActivePersons : [Person] {
        persons.filter { !activeIds.contains($0.id) }
    }
    
    func bindingForId(id: Int) -> Binding<Person> {
        .init { () -> Person in
            self.persons.first(where: { $0.id == id }) ?? Person(id: -1, name: "()")
        } set: { (newValue) in
            self.persons = self.persons.map {
                if $0.id == id {
                    return newValue
                } else {
                    return $0
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var state = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(state.activePersons, id: \.self) { person in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: EditPerson(person: state.bindingForId(id: person.id)),
                            label: {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(person.name)
                                        .font(.system(size: 26, weight: .regular))
                         
                                }.padding(15)
                            })
                    }
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: NewPerson(state: state),
                        label: {
                            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                                .font(.system(size: 26, weight: .light))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.7, green: 0.7, blue: 0.7))
                                .padding(15)
                        })
                }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 30)
                .navigationTitle("Participants")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                Text("Planning")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditPerson : View {
    @Binding var person : Person
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $person.name)
    }
}

struct NewPerson: View {
    @ObservedObject var state : AppState
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(state.nonActivePersons, id: \.self) { person in
                Button(action: {
                    state.activeIds.append(person.id)
                }) {
                    Text(person.name)
                }
            }
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 30)
    }
}
```

In this case, I'm creating an ObservableObject called `AppState`. It has @Published properties -- @Published will signal a view to refresh when the value has changed (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/observable-objects-environment-objects-and-published)

You can see that when `NewPerson` is called, the entire state object is passed as a parameter to it.

For the `EditPerson` view, I pass just a `Binding` to a `Person` -- Bindings allow two-way communication in SwiftUI (https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/04/08/binding-in-swiftui/)

Because you have an array of `Persons`, I have to do a bit of work to get a direct Binding, unless you want to use array indexes, which are a little fragile. You can see how I get a Binding based on id in the function `bindingForId`.

I also have computed properties for `activePersons` and `nonActivePersons` -- when one of the `@Published` values gets changed, these computed properties will get re-computed.

---

Another one of my answers that you might find relevant is: [How can I change an @State Variable from an other View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66925501/how-can-i-change-an-state-variable-from-an-other-view/66925629#66925629)

Comment: This works great, thanks!

One thing, however, is not yet perfect: when I select a new person, the view temporarily switches to the parent view, then goes to the new person view again.

For my purpose, the perfect choice would be that, after I have selected a new person, the view changes to edit view for this very person. Is it possible to switch from one detail view to another?